# data sharing between two realm users

Tags: android, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am developing a project in which I am trying my hand on Realm.
Its auto syncing functionality is awesome but now I want to share data between two realm users.

So Scenario is: Say I have two users "A" and "B", When "A" update anything in table "X" then "B" should be able to see those changes, so basically they both are dealing with the same table and not two realms.

If this is not possible than I have heard/read about realm functions, So by using functions can we add/update B's realm whenever "A" update his realm with the same data?

Comment: did you get this working?

Answer (score 0):

Letting multiple users work together on a realm is one of the use cases for [Realm Object Server](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/overview/#the-realm-object-server). You can use [android demo app](https://realm.io/docs/get-started/android-demo-app/) as a starting point.